# Can not find declaration of element 'xml'

Tags: python, xml, validation

I'm getting a lot of parsing errors from python related to my xml file.  I read elsewhere on stackoverflow that I should validate the xml file first.

I can't understand why this xml will not validate:

```
<xml><hive name="myprojectname">
```

XML validator says this
Error:  Can not find declaration of element 'xml'. 
Error Position:  `<xml><hive name="myprojectname">`

Comment: What XML validator are you using? What options are you passing it? Why are you using `xml` as the name of your root node?

Comment: I'm using http://www.validome.org/xml/validate/

Comment: I'm not sure about "root node" - I'm just using a xml file I was given for the project.  All the examples have this format.

Comment: Have you posted just error message or the entire XML file? The fragment you have submitted is not a valid XML document. Neither the "xml" not "hive" tags have been closed. It's more likely you have posted the error message.... In which case we can't help you without seeing what is being validated....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
<xml><hive name="myprojectname">
```

doesn't validate in http://www.validome.org/xml/validate/, because first you have to check "Well-Formedness only" option there.

Second, it have to follow XML rules, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML#Well-formedness_and_error-handling. So this should look:

```
<xml><hive name="myprojectname"/></xml>
```

Answer (score 1):

The validator you are using appears to be a DTD based validator. Unless you tell it to check for well formedness only (in which case it won't check if your elements and attributes are correct, just that you open/close elements in a sane order, quote your attribute values, etc) then you must start the XML document with a [Doctype](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Type_Definition) so that it can find the DTD.

Comment: Thanks for that response.  I have a feeling that the validation is not my problem, as the python scripts I was given have been working with these xml files (for other people).  It may be that the problem is something else.
I'm new here - sorry if I'm getting this wrong.  Should I rather post the python errors in a new question?