# Parsing XML exception

Tags: python, xml, parsing, module, elementtree

I'm new to python, and seriously need help!  I have a number of errors I can't figure out.  I'm using python 2.7 on a mac.  Here is the list of errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "minihiveosc.py", line 378, in <module>
    swhive = SWMiniHiveOSC( options.host, options.hport, options.ip, options.port, options.minibees, options.serial, options.baudrate, options.config, [1,options.minibees], options.verbose, options.apimode )
  File "minihiveosc.py", line 280, in __init__
    self.hive.load_from_file( config )
  File "/Users/Puffin/Documents/python/pydon/pydon/pydonhive.py", line 396, in load_from_file
    hiveconf = cfgfile.read_file( filename )
  File "/Users/Puffin/Documents/python/pydon/pydon/minibeexml.py", line 116, in read_file
    tree = ET.parse( filename )
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1183, in parse
    tree.parse(source, parser)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 656, in parse
    parser.feed(data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1643, in feed
    self._raiseerror(v)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1507, in _raiseerror
    raise err
xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 164, column 8
```

Any chance someone can help me?
Thanks!

Comment: Please post only one problem per question. :-)

Comment: There is only one problem here; the traceback tells you where and how Python got to it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you posted in your question is called a "Traceback", and it shows only *one* error:

> xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 164, column 8

All the lines before it show how python got there; in the file `minihiveosc.py`, on line 378 some code was executed (shown in the traceback), which then led to line 280 of the same file, where something else was called, etc.

Every time Python calls a function the current state is pushed onto the stack to make room for the next context, and when an exception occurs python can show you this stack to help you diagnose your problem

In this case, you are trying to feed an XML document to the XML parser that has an error in it; by the time the parser gets to line 164, column 8, it found something it didn't expect. You'll need to inspect that document to see what the problem is, it'll be around that area.

Answer (score 1):

It just because that your XML file is not wellformed at line 8. When the parser tries to read that line it raises that error. Have a look at your document to see what it is.

Answer (score 0):

This is one error with stack trace. 
Creation of SWMiniHiveOSC object caused error when executing load_from_file(config) method. File name or file content is in 'options.config'. Your XML config file is not well-formed, there is invalid token at line 164, column 8 in this file. The problem is with XML file, not python code.

Comment: Thank you - it's odd.  The file had 164 lines, I don't know what was wrong with the last line...I removed a whole lot of configs in the file I didn't need, saved the file again, and it seems to be working!

Comment: You can check what is wrong with XML file in Visual Studio, or online e.g. http://www.validome.org/xml/validate/ (check "Well-Formedness only")

Comment: Yes, I did that, but that didn't help me unfortunately. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11280232/can-not-find-declaration-of-element-xml